# SAP UI5: NumericContent: scale is shorted

Tags: sapui5

I am having a problem while using SAP UI5. I am using a NumericContent Tile. Here I want to set "km/h" as a scale, but it always gets abbriged to "km/".

How can I prevent this?

[image]

```
<TileContent footer="{i18nExtended>SpeedTripMax}" class="sapUiSmallMargin">
            <content>
                    <NumericContent value="{mymodel>/SpeedTripMax}"
                    truncateValueTo="6" scale="km/h"/>
            </content>
        </TileContent>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know why it is happening, but according to [api](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.suite.ui.commons.NumericTile.html) one should use sap.suite.ui.commons.GenericTile instead of sap.suite.ui.commons.NumericTile because it is deprecated since version 1.25.

Try [GenericTile](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#docs/api/symbols/sap.m.GenericTile.html) approach.

EDITED 10:42 120717:

I tested it on my system and it is bug, because k/h works fine:

[image]

[image]

The max string length is just 3 signs:

[image]

I was testing it within GenericTile.